# Will a Java thread ID stay the same for the full stack?

Tags: java, java-threads

If I call `Thread.currentThread().getId()`, I get a long representing the current thread ID.

I'm using the thread ID for a user-threadId mapping in a SessionContext class I am writing. When a user makes an API call to the backend, I store the current threadId against their userId, so then at any point I can call SessionContext.getUserId(), and it will use the threadId to map me back to the user. However this approach won't work if the result of `Thread.currentThread().getId()` changes at any point in the stack.

My question is, will this ID remain unchanged for the full stack?

Comment: I am aware this ID gets reused by new threads and that any asynchronous calls will start up a thread with a new ID that branches off the original.

Comment: [The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()). It's unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: What do you mean "for the full stack"? Which stack?

Comment: What is meant by the "full stack"? One thread is one thread(with one unique id) until you spawn another one but then there are two thread with two ids.

Comment: Well, I would believe this depends on how the request are manage. If I implement a socket server, I create a new thread for each connection. If the server create a new thread for each call (that would make sense), the ID will be different on each call, it might use some sort of Pool for short term. You just need to test it. What is you backend running on ?

Comment: @AxelH For each new call from the web client I reset the userId-threadId mapping I store. The backend is using jersey restful web-services.

Comment: I think I might be confusing terminology. The Java stack is really just describing the current thread right?

Comment: Why do you need to store the thread id? Couldn't you just store the whole `Thread` object?

Comment: @MCEmperor, I don't need to store the whole object. Using the threadId as a key in a threadID-userID map will suit my purpose fine. Thanks for the followup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()) is pretty clear about it:

> Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.

I think that's the whole point of an id — that it remains the same for its lifetime.